# A lemma for substitution theorem proof

Tags: logic, substitution

This lemma is what i want to proof (in propositional logic):

$I(B_1\leftrightarrow B_2) \leq I(A[p_i/B_1] \leftrightarrow A[p_i/B_2]) $

This is what i have done:

For $I(B_1\leftrightarrow B_2)=0$ right handside of $\leq$ isn't important so we just do the induction for $I(B_1\leftrightarrow B_2)=1$

\begin{equation} 
P=Atoms \\ \text{IB}: A\in P \begin{cases} \text{$I(B_1 \leftrightarrow B_2)=1$ }&\quad\text{if $A = p_i$} \\
 \text{$I(A \leftrightarrow A)=1$}&\quad\text{if $A \neq p_i$} \end{cases}
\\ \text{IS} : 1 \leq I(C[p_i/B_1] \leftrightarrow C[p_i/B_2]) \\\Rightarrow I(C[p_i/B_1] 
 \leftrightarrow C[p_i/B_2]) =1 \\1 \leq I(D[p_i/B_1] \leftrightarrow D[p_i/B_2]) \\\Rightarrow I(D[p_i/B_1] 
 \leftrightarrow D[p_i/B_2]) =1 \\ \vdots \\(\text{how?})\\ \vdots \\ I\Big(\left(C[p_i/B_1] \circ D[p_i/B_1]\right) \leftrightarrow \left(C[p_i/B_2] \circ D[p_i/B_2]\right) \Big)=1 \\ \circ \in \left\{ \land,\lor,\rightarrow \right\}  \end{equation}

I dont know how to reach there.

[Update:]

I consider every connectives, but i think my proof is too long , this is what i proof in my whiteboard:

[image: whiteboard proof]

Comment: Induction. You have the base case: atoms. Now consider connectives.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I did that but i guess my proof is too long, i took a picture of my whiteboard and add it to my question, can you check that please ?